# The process started from chrome location /opt/chrome/stable is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed

Tags: docker, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, aws-lambda, selenium-chromedriver

I am building a Docker container to run a Selenium scraper on AWS lambda.
However when testing the function I always get the response:

```
{"statusCode": 404, "headers": {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, "body": "An error occured: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.\n  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)\n  (The process started from chrome location /opt/chrome/stable is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)\nStacktrace:\n#0 0x563a1d2262b9 <unknown>\n"}
```

This is what the configuration of the selenium driver looks like in my code:

```
def get_chromedriver(use_proxy=False, user_agent=None):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--headless=new')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
    options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    options.binary_location = "/opt/chrome/stable"
    if use_proxy:
        pluginfile = './proxy_auth_plugin.zip'

        with zipfile.ZipFile(pluginfile, 'w') as zp:
            zp.writestr("manifest.json", manifest_json)
            zp.writestr("background.js", background_js)
        options.add_extension(pluginfile)
    if user_agent:
        options.add_argument('--user-agent=%s' % user_agent)
    service = Service("/opt/chromedriver/stable/chromedriver")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=service)
    return driver
```

My Dockerfile looks like the following:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.10 as base

RUN yum install -y -q unzip
RUN yum install -y https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm

COPY install-browser.sh /tmp/
RUN /usr/bin/bash /tmp/install-browser.sh


COPY requirements.txt /tmp/
RUN pip install --upgrade pip -q
RUN pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt -q


COPY /crawler/ ./

CMD ["app.lambda_handler"]
```

The install-browser.sh file looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

declare -A chrome_versions

# Enter the list of browsers to be downloaded
### Using Chromium as documented here - https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium
chrome_versions=( ['89.0.4389.47']='843831' )
chrome_drivers=( "89.0.4389.23" )
#firefox_versions=( "86.0" "87.0b3" )
#gecko_drivers=( "0.29.0" )

# Download Chrome
for br in "${!chrome_versions[@]}"
do
    echo "Downloading Chrome version $br"
    mkdir -p "/opt/chrome/stable"
    curl -Lo "/opt/chrome/stable/chrome-linux.zip" \
    "https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/chromium-browser-snapshots/o/Linux_x64%2F${chrome_versions[$br]}%2Fchrome-linux.zip?alt=media"
    unzip -q "/opt/chrome/stable/chrome-linux.zip" -d "/opt/chrome/stable/"
    mv /opt/chrome/stable/chrome-linux/* /opt/chrome/stable/
    rm -rf /opt/chrome/stable/chrome-linux "/opt/chrome/stable/chrome-linux.zip"
done

# Download Chromedriver
for dr in ${chrome_drivers[@]}
do
    echo "Downloading Chromedriver version $dr"
    mkdir -p "/opt/chromedriver/stable/"
    curl -Lo "/opt/chromedriver/stable//chromedriver_linux64.zip" \
    "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$dr/chromedriver_linux64.zip"
    unzip -q "/opt/chromedriver/stable//chromedriver_linux64.zip" -d "/opt/chromedriver/stable/"
    chmod +x "/opt/chromedriver/stable/chromedriver"
    rm -rf "/opt/chromedriver/stable/chromedriver_linux64.zip"
done

echo "Chrome & Chromedriver installed"
```

When I exec into the container and use a shell I can find the /opt/chromedriver/stable folder in which the chrome driver file is located. Inside the /opt/chrome/stable/ folder are the following files:

chrome                  chrome_sandbox  crashpad_handler  libGLESv2.so  nacl_helper            nacl_irt_x86_64.nexe  resources.pak            xdg-mime
chrome_100_percent.pak  chrome-wrapper  icudtl.dat        locales       nacl_helper_bootstrap  product_logo_48.png   swiftshader              xdg-settings
chrome_200_percent.pak  ClearKeyCdm     libEGL.so         MEIPreload    nacl_helper_nonsfi     resources             v8_context_snapshot.bin

I also ran the command:

> google-chrome --headless=new --disable-gpu --no-sandbox --window-size=1920,1080 --disable-dev-shm-usage

in the container and got the error:

```
[346:367:1006/091945.781500:ERROR:bus.cc(406)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[346:372:1006/091945.789999:ERROR:bus.cc(406)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[346:372:1006/091945.790122:ERROR:bus.cc(406)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[346:367:1006/091945.799010:ERROR:bus.cc(406)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[346:367:1006/091945.799070:ERROR:bus.cc(406)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[346:367:1006/091945.799089:ERROR:bus.cc(406)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[346:367:1006/091945.799103:ERROR:bus.cc(406)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[346:367:1006/091945.869164:ERROR:bus.cc(406)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[346:367:1006/091945.869231:ERROR:bus.cc(406)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[346:346:1006/091945.993855:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(576)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.portal.Settings.Read: object_path= /org/freedesktop/portal/desktop: unknown error type: 
[346:436:1006/091946.093569:ERROR:bus.cc(406)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[346:436:1006/091946.093649:ERROR:bus.cc(406)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[346:436:1006/091946.101126:ERROR:bus.cc(406)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[346:436:1006/091946.109566:ERROR:bus.cc(406)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[346:436:1006/091946.112086:ERROR:bus.cc(406)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
```

How can I resolve this error?